# Battery Drain during sleep (Wake reason: EC.ACDetach (Maintenance))

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

MBP 13" 2020 (intel)
macOS 11.7.10

My computer's battery drains from 100% to 0% over an 8-hour sleep about once a week. The wake reason is frequent EC.ACDetach (Maintenance); see the log bellow:

```
log show --style syslog --last 5h | grep "Wake reason" 
2023-12-23 04:26:34.601099+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ACDetach (Maintenance)    
2023-12-23 04:26:34.601101+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ACDetach (Maintenance)    
2023-12-23 04:26:45.697400+0800 localhost corespeechd[588]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>    
2023-12-23 04:26:45.697410+0800 localhost corespeechd[588]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2023-12-23 04:26:45.991007+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-12-23 04:26:47.030717+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-12-23 04:26:57.709689+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ACDetach (Maintenance)
2023-12-23 04:26:57.709691+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ACDetach (Maintenance)
2023-12-23 04:27:09.175080+0800 localhost corespeechd[588]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2023-12-23 04:27:09.175103+0800 localhost corespeechd[588]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2023-12-23 04:27:09.488057+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-12-23 04:27:10.420447+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-12-23 04:27:21.562825+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ACDetach (Maintenance)
2023-12-23 04:27:21.562826+0800 localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ACDetach (Maintenance)



pmset -g log | grep -e "Wake from" -e "DarkWake" -e "due to"
2023-12-23 04:26:01 +0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:15%) 6 secs    
2023-12-23 04:26:07 +0800 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:15%) 16 secs   
2023-12-23 04:26:23 +0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:15%) 7 secs    
2023-12-23 04:26:30 +0800 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:15%) 17 secs   
2023-12-23 04:26:47 +0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:15%) 6 secs    
2023-12-23 04:26:53 +0800 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:14%) 17 secs   
2023-12-23 04:27:10 +0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:14%) 6 secs
```

...
And "EC.ACDetach (Maintenance)" continues until it drains the battery completely.

Additional info:

```
pmset -g custom   
Battery Power:
 lidwake              1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 highstandbythreshold 50
 gpuswitch            2
 powernap             0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 hibernatemode        3
 displaysleep         5
 sleep                1
 tcpkeepalive         0
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 lessbright           1
 disksleep            10
AC Power:
 lidwake              1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 womp                 0
 displaysleep         10
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                1
 tcpkeepalive         0
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            10
```

The battery draining issue does not always occur. It only occurs about once a week. However, my routines are the same everyday. I don't know what triggers the "EC.ACDetach".

(Optimized Charging has been OFF, and the lid is always left closed during sleep.)

This problem appeared after my computer received a battery replacement service under AppleCare+. I brought my computer back to the Genius Bar for the battery draining issue, but the Genius Bar was no help. They said the computer passed all tests. They even tried replacing the IO port and the mainboard, but the problem persists.

Since I use this computer as a desktop, it always sleep with an external display (power off) connected to it. Battery drain will not happen if I always remember to disconnect the external display whenever I leave the computer. Before the battery replacement, I never had to bother with disconnecting and reconnecting the external display.

(Genius Bar once tested my computer with another display. The problem still exists.)

What else can I do to stop the battery drain?

Comment: CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

Comment: @Ruskes Yes, that is also a mystery to me. Does it mean that there is a problem with the S3 sleep?

Comment: If you use this as a desktop computer, why not leave it plugged in?

Answer (score 1):

Some other analytical methods include

`pmset -g log | grep -e "Wake from" -e "DarkWake" -e "due to"`

That would give you nice overview

and

Turn off the BT proximity wake just in case

`sudo pmset -b proximitywake 0`

Lets find out if you have any scheduled events that will drain power

`pmset -g sched`

Comment: Thank you. I disabled proximitywake as you suggested. I also added DarkWake log record to the post. It still points to EC.ACDetach (Maintenance). 

I also found that 90% of the time this battery draining issue occurred on Friday night thru Saturday morning, although I don't have different routines on Friday night (but the computer does by default without me knowing it?).

Comment: @isend I would like to see your `pmset -g`

Comment: `pmset -g` added to the post

Comment: @isend interesting result, your proximity-wake is still active ? Lets try to fid out if you have any Scheduled events `pmset -g sched`

Comment: proximity-wake is off for Battery Power (see the revised post; actually I think it has been off by default). `pmset -g sched` returns nothing.

Comment: @isend do you know if the SMC was reset after battery change ? SMC chip would be the one to monitor and report the `EC.ACDetach (Maintenance).`

Comment: Yes, resetting SMC is the first thing I tried when I found this issue. Actually the macOS was clean-installed in the machine after several different attempts to solve this problem did not work.

Comment: @isend Change hibernation mode to 25 (from currently 3), which means full hibernation, aka not powering RAM. to do that, use the following command from terminal app:
`pmset -b hibernatemode 25` 
Downside of this is slower wake up, but since SSDs are pretty fast these days, it's not that big a problem anymore.

Comment: Actually I had been using `hibernatemode 25`, but was forced to switch to `hibernatemode 3` after battery replacement, because `hibernatemode 25` ALWAYS triggers EC.ACDetach (Maintenance) and drains the battery. `hibernatemode 3` triggers EC.ACDetach (Maintenance) about only once a week.

Comment: @isend If I run `pmset -g log | grep -e "EC.ACDetach"` I get two messages-- 2023-12-20 23:37:27 -0700 DarkWake DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNP] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance Using AC (Charge:100%) 6 secs 2023-12-21 23:01:36 -0700 DarkWake DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:100%) 45 secs

Comment: `pmset -g log | grep -e "EC.ACDetach"` gave me several messages. Some are like yours. The one leading to battery drain is frequent `DarkWake  DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:3%) 7 secs` (Charge value goes from 100% to 3%)

Comment: I would say it is still the SMC acting up. Reseting it can be tricky. One way to very the reset worked is to keep holding the reset keys till the charger light briefly changes from yellow to green and back to yellow.

Comment: This model does not have a charger light. The mainboard has burnt out twice during this time. Apple replaced the mainboard twice but the "EC.ACDetach" battery drain problem persists. I suspected the new battery has an issue (keeps burning the mainboard and causing the "EC.ACDetach" issue), but the Genius Bar did not agree with me and refused to change the battery again.

Comment: OK, then use the cap lock light to verify the SMC reset

Comment: If a newly installed mainboard also have the problem, will an SMC reset help?

Comment: So you replaced the logic board and the problem persists, so it is in the software, and yes SMC reset helps since it is in new environment. But for you, run it in safe mode and let it stay like that overnight.

Comment: macOS needs to be clean-installed after the mainboard replacement. The problem was already there when I received the computer from the Genius Bar.

Comment: The EC. are normal part of operating process--- try the `pmset -a tcpkeepalive 0` in terminal

Comment: `tcpkeepalive` is already 0

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something attached to your Mac's USB slot? I had the same issue with you but I found out that it's my USB adapter that was attached to my Mac's USB slot all the time causing this issue. After removing it this issue had stopped occuring.

Comment: Yes, as described in the post, an external display (power off) is connected to the laptop. I want the laptop to be able to sleep with the external display connected to it.