# Mac slowing down / working in burst mode at night (while running Python script)

Tags: macos, performance, sleep-wake, ventura

My setup is differing performance of python code on a MacBook Pro 2021 running macOS 13.6.3.

My python script that reads data from a file on the boot volume, makes a 8192*8192 matrix, finds its eigenvalues and saves some of them to the same volume, looped over a few thousand files.

During the day, when the display is on or off, each loop iteration takes about 10 seconds.

However at night the script slows right down and works in bursts: it goes through a handful (4-6) loop iterations at 10 sec each, then "rests" for 10-20 minutes, then does another burst.

I have set System Settings > Displays > Advanced > "Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off" to on, so it shouldn't be sleeping.

I am like ~80% sure that this wasn't happening before I updated from MacOS 12.

What could be causing this slowdown/burst mode at night, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Since you tagged this sleep-wake are you thinking that somehow the Mac is sleeping and waking? Or would an [answer to tell you which console messages indicate sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/467737/5472) help? This is a better spot for this topic than SO in my opinion, so I’ll remove that “meta” from your question body and we can discuss further in [chat] or on [meta] here as needed…

Comment: Not really an answer, but a potential solution: use the tool amphetamine and it'll keep your Mac awake for as long as you want

Comment: @bmike I'm not sure if the Mac is sleeping and waking in this case, as I have disabled sleep when the power adapter is connected. Maybe the process that I launch when I run the python script is sleeping. In the SO forum someone commented App Nap, so it could be this.

Comment: @X_841 thanks. I used Insomniax on my previous 2015MBP, is amphetamine a similar thing? Will it work with the 2021MBP?

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/de/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12, works for me on my MBP 2017 with macOS Ventura