# My 2019 intel MacBook is dying in sleep while unplugged any ideas on how to fix?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, sleep-wake

I'm getting "DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance" every minute or so in the sleep logs and it never really gets to sleep. Any ideas?

I have reset PRAM, SMC, and reinstalled the OS. Problem did not show up in safe mode, but hard to certify because the issue doesn't show up every day.

Comment: Possibly related or even a duplicate: [Battery Drain during sleep (Wake reason: EC.ACDetach (Maintenance))](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467726/battery-drain-during-sleep-wake-reason-ec-acdetach-maintenance)

Comment: This is a 5 year old MacBook - batteries have an expected lifespan of 3 to 5 years.  It is most likely the battery is no longer holding a charge properly.

Comment: Can you post the output of the command `system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -i "charge information" -A 10` with an [edit] to the original question?

Comment: If the problem does not appear in Safe Mode, that would suggest that the cause is some third-party extensions, Launch Agents or other processes. When you reinstalled the OS, did you also keep all your stuff in place, or restore it?  But I agree that the first thing to check is the condition of the battery. How many cycles, what percentage of original charge is it holding?